# yii how to update user fields without changing affecting on password

Tags: php, yii

How can i update, some field, forexample firstname or lastname or email without doing any change on password field
My model

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('username, salt,  password, firstname, lastname, email', 'required', 'on' ),
        array('superuser, status', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('username, password, salt', 'length', 'max'=>32),
        array('firstname, lastname,image', 'length', 'max'=>80),
        array('email', 'length', 'max'=>128),

        array('id, username, password, salt, firstname, lastname, email,  superuser, status', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

AND in model i have

```
public function beforeValidate()
{


    $this->salt = '1294455567';
    return parent::beforeValidate();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Yii scenarions](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/#hh3). For example in your model you has next validation rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('username, salt, password, firstname, lastname, email', 'required', 'on' => 'create'),
        array('email, username, firstname, lastname', 'someValidationRuleOrMethod', 'on' => 'update'),
    );
}
```

When you need to create new user, need to set validation scenario:

```
$model = new User('create');
//some code
$model->validate();
```

Or:

```
$model = new User();
$model->scenario = 'create';
//some code
$model->validate();
```

When you need update exists user - use `update` scenario instead `create`:

```
$model = User::model()->findByPk($someId);
$model->scenarion = 'update';
//some code
$model->validate();
```

Also, I found this [receipt](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/cookbook/ru/model.update.specified.field) on Russian Yii blog.

**UPD** You can use static method to hash password, and can call it every where:

```
public static function hashPassword($password)
{
    return CPasswordHelper::hashPassword($password);
}
```

Comment: Thank for responce. but problem is that in action i call User::model()-<findByPk($id), and in the form i have allready password field, and when saving changes, even if i dont load password field in form, the password field also writing in DB, no matter field required or not via scenario. how to do save() or update() without password?

Comment: If you has someting like this: ``$model = User::model()->findByPk($someId); $model->attributes = Yii::app()->request->getPost('User');`` and in post array password is not exists, your password not be rewritten in db (this work in case if you not do anything with password in model methods)

Comment: you are wrong!, even if getPost('User') has no field password, $model->password already has value, and via beforesave() do     `$this->password = $this->hashPassword($this->password, $this->salt);`

Comment: Please, read my comment attentively! I said: ``(this work in case if you not do anything with password in model methods)``

Comment: One of the best practices use few form models: for login, register, restore password, etc. So, you will need hash password only in register form model

Comment: Sorry. i think to create some variable in my `user` model. then in `UserController` action set some values. and in `beforeSave()` check if false, then do nothing on password, and write in DB hashed value. But is this right metod to solve my small problem?

Comment: it's looks like a "spike". Why do you not want to use form models, such as: register, login?

Comment: Let me explain, for admin user i have `user/create` and `user/update`. Forms for this action`s views contain password field. here i have no problem. But for standart user i create `user/edit`  and form for this action contain only firstname, lastname and email. and for this action also have `User::model()->findByPk($someId)`

Comment: You need hash password only: 1. when user register account, 2. restore password, 3. admin change user password (if it has this ability). Why hash password every time when you update user details? So, hash password should not be in ``beforeSave()`` method

Comment: I think you need static method, which hash password, and you can call it every where you need. Please see my updated code

Comment: You are welcome, i've added example for password hashing, maybe it will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this also...

```
    public function beforeSave()
    {
            if(!$this->getIsNewRecord())
                 unset($this->password);
            return parent::beforeSave();
    }
```

Hope it may help you..

Comment: Are you sure, what your code will be working if need to update password for exists user?

Comment: As I understand you everytime skip password for exists user in model? how you restore password if user want change it or forgot password?

Comment: for that i have created separate view file call resetpassword and i am dealing with password

Comment: Sorry, I not fully understand, you overrided model ``beforeSave()`` method, for reset password you use special method, not the ``save()``?

Answer (score 0):

Create a User model object for single user, then update by assigning new value for field:

```
...
$user = User::model()->find("`t`.`username` = :USER", array(':USER' => 'example.user'));
$user->firstname = 'New First Name';
$user->lastname = 'New Last Name';
$user->email = 'email@user.new';

# Now update User here
if($user->update()) {
    echo 'Updated';
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi all what i have done is here....

My controller ::

public function actionUpdate($id){
        $model=$this->loadModel($id,'User');

```
    $oldImage           = $model->image;
   // $old_password       = $model->password;
    $model->password    = '';


    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['User']))
    {

        $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];

        //If image not uploaded then set old image
        if(!$this->uploadImage($model)){
            $model->image    = $oldImage;
        }

        if($model->save()){

            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "Data Updated successfully"); // Flash Message
            $this->redirect(array('admin','id'=>$model->user_id));
        }

    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

**My Model**

```
    public function rules()
    {



            // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
            // will receive user inputs.
            return array(
                array('first_name, last_name, password, email,repeat_password', 'required',"on"=>'create'),
                array('first_name, last_name, email', 'required',"on"=>'update'),
                array('first_name, last_name', 'length', 'max'=>100),
                array('password', 'length', 'max'=>30,'min'=>6),
                array('repeat_password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password', 'message'=>'Confirm Password must be same as password'),
                array('email', 'length', 'max'=>50),
                array('email', 'unique'),
                //array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png'),
                array('image', 'safe'),
                // The following rule is used by search().
                // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
                array('user_id, first_name, last_name, email', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
            );


    }
public function beforeSave(){


        if(!empty($this->password))
            $this->password = md5($this->password);
        else
            unset($this->password);


        return parent::beforeSave();

    }
```

**My View ::**

```
 <?php
        // If user update profile or update data then don't show password
        if( ((@Yii::app()->request->getParam('act')!=="profile") && empty($_GET["id"])) || @$_GET["act"]=='changepwd' )
        {

     ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('maxlength'=>20,'minlength'=>6)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row"><!-- Confirm password -->
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Confirm Password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'repeat_password',array('maxlength'=>20,'minlength'=>6)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'repeat_password'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

public function actionUpdate($id) {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

```
    if(isset($_POST['User']))
    {
        $password = $model->password;  
        $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
        if($password === $model->password) {
            $model->password = $password;    
        } else {
            $model->password = md5(SALT . $model->password);        
        }
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Would be great if you explain the code for better understanding.

Comment: How you compare password from post with stored password, if stored password is hash?